# How can I select data from 3 tables in sql?

Tags: sql, database

I have 3 tables:

```
create table user (
    user_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    username string not null,
    email string not null,
    pw_hash string not null
);


create table product (
    product_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    productname string not null,
    productdescription string not null,
);

create product_review (
    product_id integer,
    user_id integer,
    review,
);
```

Now, I want to display all the reviews from user_id=1. A simple query for this would be
    select * from product_review where user_id = 1

However, I want the data listed as -->

```
username  productname review
John      iPad3       Super awesome
John      SonyVaio    Even more awesome
```

Comment: Is this homework? Because what you're looking for is called a `join`

Comment: no it's not homework :). I am working on web app, and so needed it. I did read on JOIN's before posting but most had examples with two tables. I will definitely read more. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT username, productname, review
  FROM user a INNER JOIN product_review pr
    ON a.user_id = pr.user_id INNER JOIN product p
    ON p.product_id = pr.product_id
 WHERE a.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Also, the OP should read up on [SQL Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

Comment: This is mostly just me being picky, however, I would have the first table selected from be the product_review table and the where clause be on its user_id field. Due to indexing it will likely be negligible, but if there are users in the users table without reviews, the JOIN will still be attempted onto the product_review table for those rows. Additionally, depending on the optimization of the database software, it might skip this, but it might join the tables and then do the where clause. If the where clause is executed on the product_review tables only though, some joins can possibly be avoi

Comment: @Cybernate: You should have mentioned also that this would drop bought products without any product_review(`OUTER JOIN`).

Comment: @Tim: Agreed. However OP clearly mentioned that "I want to display all the reviews from user_id=1"

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed. I wasn't sure how to combine two joins.